# jQuery removeClass on parent/sibling/child

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery to change classes on elements in an unordered list.  It doesn't seem like it is the most effective way of achieving the effect.  Is there a better way to write this?

```
$(function() {
    $('nav li a').click( function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Thanks

S

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's usually simpler in these cases to attach the handler to the `<li>` and let the click [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) from the `<a>` (which happens by default).  Then your handler looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('nav li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Then in your CSS you just account for `active` being on the `<li>`, like this:

```
li.active a { color: red; }
```

As an aside, if you have many `<li>` elements you'll want to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like this:

```
$('nav').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Also note that if you want to remove `'active'` from all elements except `this` then you could get away with something as simple as

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

And that should propagate through the tree pretty easily. However, I can see it causing a headache on performance if the DOM is heavily populated.

Answer (score 1):

I used above code, it is working

I am using in my code

```
enter code here : function addnewStepsUpper(){
jQuery('.hide_upper_clone_class').clone().insertAfter(".upper_clone_class1");
jQuery('.upper_clone_class1').siblings().removeClass('hide_upper_clone_class');
```

}

Thanks
Vishal Sanwar

Answer (score 1):

$(this).addClass('active').parent('li').siblings().children().removeClass('active');